# MYSQL ID not in order

Tags: mysql

i have a problem with MySQL. My table has a ID, but when i select the data and order by ID ASC, the id is out of order.

[image]

As you can see, after WI10 the ID is WI100, the ID should be WI11. Any solutions? Sorry for my bad eng, thank you!

Comment: In the given screenshot, there is no `ID` column

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is this table made by you or just imported

Comment: @NicoHaase Sorry, my id column named cId

Comment: @Kalana i want make an input form, and i need last row inserted in that table to get the id. My id Column not auto increment, so i custom by myself

Comment: Since your ID is not numeric this is what you get! If you made your ID numeric OR used a uniform number of digits in the numeric part of it, you wouldn't have any issue.

Comment: this is the normal situation, because of your ID column is not integer. So mysql order that column ascending like a,aa,aa,aab.... so you need to change ID column to integer or you need to use substring method to delete first 2 letter and convert it integer.

Answer (score 1):

The column `cid` is sorted alphabetically because it is not a number.
If its pattern is always like `WIXXX` you can sort the table like:

```
order by substr(cid, 3) + 0
```

This extracts the numeric part after the first 2 chars and implicitly converts it to a number.